# Get the filename if files are uploaded in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, multiple-file-upload

I want to make users to upload multiple files in PHP.

**HTML**:

```
<input name="file[]" type="file" class="multi_files" style="margin: 0px 0px 15px;" />
<button class="add_more">Add More Files</button>
```

When user selects a file,I need to show the button `Add more file`.Otherwise hide the button.On loading of page I make button with class `#add_more` hidden through jquery.Initially when first file is uploaded,add more button get displayed.This works fine.From second case onwards ,I need to show `add more` only when the next file is uploaded.Pls help me

```
$('input:file.multi_files').change(
        function(){
            $('input:file').removeClass('multi_files');
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $('.add_more').show();
            } 
            else
            {
                $('.add_more').hide();

            }
        }
        );
  $('.add_more').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   //my logic is I will check immediate input file has file or not with this condition.
  //But this condition always give me undefined value.
    if($(this).closest('input:file').val())
      {

        $(this).before("<input name='file[]' type='file' class='multi_files'/>");
      }  

});
```

I also need to add delete button for each file.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.add_more').hide();
$('input:file.multi_files').change(
        function(){
            $('input:file').removeClass('multi_files');
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $(this).after("<button class='remove'>X</button><br/>");
                $('.add_more').show();
            } 
            else
            {
                $('.add_more').hide();

            }
        }
        );

  $('body').on('click','.remove',function(){
   
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('file').length > 1 ){
      $(this).prev('input:file').remove();
      $(this).next('br').remove();
      $(this).remove();
     }
  });

  $('.add_more').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var filePresent = document.getElementsByClassName('file')[document.getElementsByClassName('file').length-1].files.length;
    if(filePresent >0  ){
        $(this).before("<input name='file[]' type='file' class='multi_files file'/><button class='remove'>X</button><br/>");
      }  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='file[]' type='file' class='multi_files file'/>
<button class="add_more">Add More</button>
```

Comment: DO you have working fiddle with you.My issue is with -$(this).prev('input:file').get(0).files.length.It is giving me undefined

Comment: I have a small issue in my page.For me delete buttons are coming together.

Comment: Is it a CSS issue you are talking about?

Comment: I will upload the screen shot

Comment: You can actually wrap the input and delete button together in a span or div tag, so that they appear in correct manner. If you could also share a screenshot of how you would want them?

Comment: I want them like this:   file_name delete button <next-line>file delete button<next-line>file delete button <new line>Add more

Comment: Please check the answer now.

Comment: Vacant spaces are coming if I delete some files between some files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97766/discussion-between-sahil-and-techy).

Comment: Have you check the code.Try to add multiple files now.browse button is not coming